# Correct syntax for fadeOut #id = javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code there are a couple of  tags that can be clicked. On click I want the corresponding image to fadeOut. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var url = id.replace('ServiceClick', '');
$("#'url'").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var url = id.replace('ServiceClick', '');
   $("#"+url).fadeOut();
```

**$("#'url'")** only work with an element with id like

```
<span id="''url''">test</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, at least now I have the right syntax. It doesn't fadeOut by id though, only by class :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you have incorrect `$("#" + url)`

```
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = id.replace('ServiceClick', '');
    $("#" + url).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var url = id.replace('ServiceClick', '');
$("#"+url).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append # with url

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var url = id.replace('ServiceClick', '');
$("#" + url).fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var url = id.replace('ServiceClick', '');
$("#"+url).fadeOut(100); <-- add milliseconds
```